# Why would my Kenmore front-loader washer very intermittently not drain?

Tags: appliances

Sometimes, maybe one in every 20 or 30 or even 50 loads of wash, I'll go to the washing machine and it'll be off just like it normally is after it's completed its full cycle, but when I open the door, water gushes out. Of course, instinctively, I immediately try to push the door back closed, but almost always some article of clothing has made its way far enough across the threshold in that gush of water that I'm prevented from being able to reclose the door, so I've just got to press against it as water slowly drains out.

Fortunately, I have a floor drain about a foot from the front of the washer, so at least the water has somewhere to go, but unfortunately, it's also about two feet from the entry door to my laundry room, outside which the floor is Pergo, which is extremely easily damaged by water. So it usually involves me calling out for help and having someone come and create some kind of towel dam to block off the hallway and I then have to proceed to slowly let the water out by slightly releasing pressure on the door and/or accessing the little pannel just below the door where there's a little drain tube I can unplug and extend so the water drains from it directly into the drain.

Why would my washer be doing this, and doing it so intermittently? It happens with enough rarity that just when you think it's not going to happen again, it suddenly does and you're totally caught off guard. Also, logic would tell me that the same sensors inside that weigh the load and so forth in calculating the wash cycle should also know that it's either not completed its cycles or, if it has but something just kept draining from happening, know it's still full of water, thus not releasing the locking mechanism that normally keeps you from opening the door when it's running and got water in it. So that's a head-scratcher, too.

The only thing I've tried or could find to try to try and address this is clean the filter/lint trap that's accessed through the same panel on the front of the washer where the little emergency drain hose is located. So that much I've tried but it's never made a lick of difference.

Also, I at first thought maybe this was happening because of overloading, like the load itself was preventing the draining somehow, like from being overly heavy or in some way obstructing the draining, but it's continued to happen even after reducing load size, and then once, it happened even with just a couple handfuls of baby clothes in it, which was hardly a load at all.

Comment: Something like this is almost impossible to diagnose unless it has happen to someone else and found.  Imagine it is something that is just not broken enough to find, maybe to do with temperature of something(say 60 and below is perfect, 62 it happens).  Probably the only way to find the problem is to replace pieces/parts one by one till it stops.  This is the most expensive and time waste way of finding a problem and never recommend.

Comment: It could also be that a contact on a timer switch or relay is worn or dirty, making imperfect contact on occasion.

Comment: Faulty water level sensor in the machine. Replace it.

Comment: Give me the exact model and I will tell you more

Comment: Thanks, @Ruskes. The exact model number inside the door says Model No. 41162410, but the owner's manual just says Kenmore 41162.

Comment: OK, you and me can now look for the water level sensor for that model

Comment: I found this, what did you find ? https://www.appliancepartspros.com/lg-switch-assm-sensor-6601er1006e-ap4440713.html

Comment: I guess Ruskes knows!  But I was wondering if the spin and drain was having trouble because of bad balance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete model number - that will make it easier for everyone how may read your question.

Comment: @aparente001 - Thanks for the thought. It's not because of balance, though. Mine's perfectly balanced, nary a shimmy or a sake from it ever. I've seen some people's that seem like they're bringing down the house when they go into the spin cycle. Mine, though, is rock solid.